# Error: Missing redirect_uri parameter

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am trying to access to my Facebook app using the code bellow:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String domain = "http://www.google.com/";
                String appId = "524606967732411";
                String authUrl ="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&clientid="+appId+"&redirect_url="+domain+"&scope=user_about_me,";/*
                        +"user_actions.books,user_actions.music,user_actions.news,user_actions.videos,user_activities,user_birthday,user_education_history"
                        +"user_events,user_photos,user_friends,user_games_avtivity,user_groups,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_photos,user_relationship_details,"
                        +"user_relationships,user_religion_politics,user_status,user_tagged_places,user_videos,user_website,user_work_history,ads_management,ads_read,email,"
                        +"manage_notifications,manage_pages,publish_actions,read_friendlists,read_insights,read_mailbox,read_page_mailboxes,read_stream,ravp_event,fo";*/
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");

                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.get(authUrl);
                String accessToken;
                while(true){
                    if(!driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("facebook.com")){
                        String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
                        accessToken = url.replaceAll(".*#access_token=(.+)&.*", "$l");
                        driver.quit();

                            FacebookClient fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);
                            User me = fbClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

the chorme is opening but it is displaying this message error :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Missing redirect_uri parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191,
      "fbtrace_id": "E0YDbab1wzS"
   }
}
```

And on the console screen is showing the following message:

[image]

I hope that someone can help with that!

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score -1):

I've noticed you are specifying `redirect_url` instead of `redirect_uri`

hope it helps

Maybe it's redundant to mention, but the error message says exactly that :)

Comment: Is this the expected answer ...?